# Is it possible to use th:attrappend with JSON type format?

Tags: thymeleaf

Let's I have one base html class (fragment) which includes basic x-bind:class attribute with the following content:

```html
 <th:block
      th:fragment="appButton(text)"
      th:with="
  attrappends=${attrappends} ?: 'data-thyme=attraappend',    
  attributes=${attributes} ?: 'data-thym=default'
  "
    >
      <button
        th:attrappend="__${attrappends}__"
        th:attr="__${attributes}__"
        th:text="${text}"
        x-bind:class="{
          'loading': $store.loadingOrDisabledState.stateVal,
        }
        "
        ,
      ></button>
    </th:block>
```

Now when i call this fragment in the html file (let's assume i want to update x-bind:class in this html)

```html
 <button
            th:replace="~{fragments/app-button :: appButton(
              text='...',
              attrappends='
              |x-bind:class|=|{'anotherCssValue' :withAnotherCondition}|,
              ',
              attributes='...
              ',
         
              )}"
          ></button>
```

My expectation is to combine all conditions in one object:

```json
{  
   'loading': $store.loadingOrDisabledState.stateVal,
   'anotherCssValue' :withAnotherCondition
}
```

But thymeleaf is producing the following value (which is not valid):

```json
{  
   'loading': $store.loadingOrDisabledState.stateVal,
}
{
   'anotherCssValue' :withAnotherCondition
}
```

?